# "okupar" and "ocupar"

Tags: solicitud-de-término

It's pretty common to find, in the net, people chatting, posting, and so on with (sometimes convenient, for shortness, but sometimes intentional) spelling mistakes:  `¿qué?` is often written `ke?`, `xq` instead of  `¿por qué?` and `awebo` stands for `a huevo`. Apparently because of this, the RAE has validated the word "okupar", derived from the 'right'-spelled word "ocupar".

This is a question rather on the evolution of the Spanish language, I guess. *Can somebody explain the reason, given by RAE, to [accept](http://dle.rae.es/okupar) `okupar` as a new word?* (Kindly notice that I'm not asking for a translation.) As for me, I don't see any reason to accept it.

> De ocupar, con k, letra que refleja una voluntad de transgresión de las normas ortográficas

By the way, it is worth to notice that RAE doesn't include any meaning for "ocupar" that remotely resembles one of the commonly accepted meanings "usar" (to use).

Comment: I looked up "ocupar" in RAE, but only got definitions for "ocupar(se)".  I might be using RAE wrongly.

Comment: Could you give an example of "ocupar" meaning "usar"?

Comment: Yes. The correct use would be "El señor ocupó el asiento del gobernador en el teatro". There is no need for refelxive. And regarding your second comment @WalterMitty, in some countries of Latin America "ocupar" means also "usar" (the rightness of this use is questionable, but everybody understands) For instance: "¿Estás ocupando tu lápiz?" means "¿estás usando tu lápiz?". By the way, comming back to your first comment, RAE's search engine is a nightmare!

Comment: "ocupar el asiento" could be taken to mean "usar". But the way you use a seat is to occupy it. I really don't think a separate dictionary entry is needed.

Comment: @WalterMitty indeed. The example you asked for was the second one: "¿Estás ocupando tu lápiz?" means "¿estás usando tu lápiz?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please note that the word *ocupar* doesn't mean the same in American Spanish (where it could be used as the word "use") and Iberian Spanish, where it is used for "take possesion" or "fill an space", among others.

Having said that, I don't think that the RAE accepting *okupar* as a new word is a sign of rule transgression or orthographic rule violations.

*Okupar* is a popular term used when someone trespasses other people's properties without their authorization, to live there (squatting). Given the recent house market bubble, a lot of people is doing that in empty houses and buildings. The use of  *k* just denotes a hint of rebellion in this context, and has been used in many urban subcultures like the punk music culture.

Comment: So, it's a meta-thing, so to say: one writes "okupar" (which violates the spelling rules) to emphasize that one violates the law, as I understand from your answer.

Comment: Somehow, but not necessarily. I think that it is also to signal a semantic distinction with the traditional use of "ocupar" (i.e. filling a space)

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware of this either: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movimiento_okupa

Comment: A similar thing happens in English were people choose to write "magick", deliberately misspelled from "magic" to differentiate the concepts (although in this case, the origin of the misspelling can be traced back to an author).

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes we forget the main goal of RAE is not *creating* the language rules (in fact, it is not **at all**), but adapting the rules to the actual and current way of use it. If there is a word like *okupar*:

- born more than 40 years ago,
- known by most part of Spanish-speakers,
- used only (or mainly) by Spanish-speakers,
- used by media,
- that adds a new meaning (I think we agree there are clear differences with *ocupar*)

then RAE's duty is accept it.

There are a lot of examples of that written above, just doing a [search on El Paìs](http://elpais.com/buscador/) throws 3656 results with the word *okupa*. Most of them are before RAE's change and the word appears in inverted commas.

Of course, it should be written with *k* if we want to give the word that meaning. If it was written this way before the rule, also now!

Answer (score 2):

**En mi opinión**, es un nefasto y tremendo error de la RAE admitir palabras de nuevo cuño con «**una voluntad de transgresión de las normas ortográficas**» a menos que su uso frecuente durante decenas de años lo hayan incorporado definitivamente al idioma, que no es el caso de las palabras relacionadas con el movimiento «okupa», que por ahora son únicamente nuevas palabras de moda debido a una fenómeno social relativamente nuevo.

El problema principal de aceptar alegremente transgresiones de las normas ortográficas con una larguísima tradición, es que nos quedamos sin normas ortográficas, y por tanto sin criterio objetivo para no incorporar  «tod@s», «xq», «awevo» o lo que apetezca en cada momento. Adiós idioma, adiós.

Pero además, «okupar» es doblemente innecesaria porque no se trata de nueva palabra como «friki» sin un claro sinónimo en español, ni una abreviatura imaginativa. Resulta que es simplemente «ocupar», un verbo de toda la vida,  pero mal escrito, y que se puede usar en lugar de «okupar» sin que cambie un ápice el significado de la frase.

Además, como fonéticamente son indistinguibles, en el español hablado no existe tal palabra, de modo que lo único que se consigue es que una única palabra se pueda pueda escribir *correctamente* de formas diferentes, pero sólo en determinados contextos. No cabe mayor inconsistencia para el idioma.

Así volvemos al *Cantar de mio Cid* donde el mismo verbo se escribía cada vez de una forma distinta, pero antes estaba naciendo un idioma y ahora nos empeñamos en su eutanasia aunque goce de buena salud.

Precisamente, el emblema original de la RAE original tenía la leyenda «**Limpia, fija y da esplendor**», porque se creó con el propósito de «**fijar las voces y vocablos de la lengua castellana en su mayor propiedad, elegancia y pureza**», y desde luego, la incorporación de «okupar» no ayuda a fijar las voces, ni a la pureza del idioma y menos aún a su elegancia. Al contrario, es un ataque en toda regla a los propios principios fundacionales de la RAE.

Ojalá esta ocurrencia de la actual RAE quede anulada en la práctica por las normas que ya fijaron sus antecesores y los propios hispanoparlantes, como ha ocurrido con [el intento de quitarle la tilde a «sólo» y «ésto»](http://www.elmundo.es/elmundo/2013/01/09/cultura/1357735373.html).

Comment: "Fijar" se puede entender en el sentido de "impedir que cambien" (acepción 3 del DRAE: *Hacer fijo o estable algo*), y quizás fue eso la intención de Felipe V, pero también se puede entender en el sentido de "poner claro lo que es" (acepción 4 del DRAE: *Determinar, limitar, precisar, designar de un modo cierto*, con el ejemplo de *Fijar el sentido de una palabra*). El propósito de un diccionario es que la gente pueda buscar el significado de una palabra que lee y no conoce, no es decidir cuales palabras son dignas de usar.

Comment: Véase también [esta entrevista](http://www.abc.es/cultura/cultural/20130304/abci-cultural-libros-entrevista-jose-201303041256.html) con el vicedirector de la RAE.

Answer (score 1):

This is my personal interpretation of the meaning that you transcribed on your question.

If we read carefully it does say "voluntad de transgresión" which means "a will to violate a rule".

So what I understand from that sentence is not that RAE is accepting the use of this spelling but only explaining why it is used like that or why sometimes it will be found spelled like that in some places.

IMHO you should always spell it with a "c" unless you are actually chatting and want to follow the online trends.

Comment: I disagree.  If the RAE accepted the terms to include them in the official dictionary, they're now practically part of the language.  Which in this case, sucks.  Next thing, we'll see "ke" being accepted as a replacemente for "que" =/

Comment: @mjuarez I agree with you. That's my concern. It is paradoxical to have accepted words that "will to violate a rule" (if it was more like a warning to let the Spanish speakers know that the word can be found with that spelling, then a bunch of "words" should be also included. Moreover it is marked as "jargon", so according to RAE, it's valid).

Answer (score 1):

Sé que la discusión alrededor de la pureza del lenguaje se vuelve demasiado compleja cuando se entra en la cuestión de la lengua y el habla. La distinción semántica que se hace solo por el uso de la "k" en lugar de la "c", me parece meramente política. Realmente no veo la necesidad de crear un nuevo verbo que significa casi lo mismo; las palabras no obtienen su significado por sí mismas, sino en relación al contexto, de modo que si se está hablando de la ocupación ilegal de una propiedad, realmente puedo seguir usando la misma palabra. 
También me preocupa que si la RAE ha optado la posición de aceptar todo cuanto es usado por el hablante, eventualmente estaremos escribiendo como hablamos. Ya en la antigua Roma se distinguía el lenguaje hablado del escrito, y siendo el español un derivado del latín, es normal que se encuentre esta misma distinción. 
Las reglamentación de la lengua busca darle un orden y una estructuración determinada; el habla es tan libre como el individuo que la usa. Hay que tener mucho cuidado, pues si seguimos como vamos, os encontraremos con un español escrito sin pies ni cabeza.